# Does using a volume while using the docker provision not work?

Tags: docker, vagrant

The aim is to run a docker container that uses volumes by using Vagrant's docker provisioner.

```
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.run "rancher/agent", 
      image: "rancher/agent:v1.2.5",
      cmd: "some cmd",
      args: "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher"
  end
```

Attempt to solve the issue

In order to try to solve the issue, the shell provisioning was used:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker run --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.2.5 some cmd"
```

Now the container is able to start. Why does the docker provision fail to mount volumes?